# Perl: Use s/ (replace) and return new string

Tags: regex, perl, replace

In Perl, the operator `s/` is used to replace parts of a string. Now `s/` will alter its parameter (the string) in place. I would however like to replace parts of a string befor printing it, as in

```
print "bla: ", replace("a","b",$myvar),"\n";
```

Is there such `replace` function in Perl, or some other way to do it? `s/` will not work directly in this case, and I'd like to avoid using a helper variable. Is there some way to do this in-line?

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but the phrasing of the question is valuable to those users that are new, and/or porting code, to Perl.  Also, just in my opinion, the answers here are more concise in answering this specific question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
require 5.013002; # or better:    use Syntax::Construct qw(/r);
print "bla: ", $myvar =~ s/a/b/r, "\n";
```

See [perl5132delta](https://perldoc.pl/5.14.0/perl5132delta#Non-destructive-substitution):

> The substitution operator now supports a `/r` option that copies the input variable, carries out the substitution on the copy and returns the result. The original remains unmodified.

```
my $old = 'cat';
my $new = $old =~ s/cat/dog/r;
# $old is 'cat' and $new is 'dog'
```

Comment: Well whaddya know!  Very handy.  Had I known about this I would have used it about 80% of the time!

Comment: Ah, now I see it's actually very recent...  Perl 5.13.2.  So it's still of interest to look for workarounds for older versions.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Perl 5.14 or greater, you can use the `/r` option with the substitution operator to perform [non-destructive substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JESSE/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Non-destructive-substitution):

```
print "bla: ", $myvar =~ s/a/b/r, "\n";
```

In earlier versions you can achieve the same using a [`do()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) block with a temporary lexical variable, e.g.:

```
print "bla: ", do { (my $tmp = $myvar) =~ s/a/b/; $tmp }, "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print "bla: ", $myvar =~ tr{a}{b},"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "bla: ", $_, "\n" if ($_ = $myvar) =~ s/a/b/g or 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why the "if"?

Comment: @sleske : What if `$myvar` doesn't contain an `a`. In that case, `$_` would be undefined. It's also why the `or 1` has been added in this answer, to force the `print` to go ahead even if there isn't anything to substitute. Not terribly readable IMO.

Comment: @Zaid: ? $_ would not be undefined; it was just set to $myvar.  This is better done as `($_ = $myvar) =~ s/a/b/g, print "bla: ", $_, "\n"`

Comment: @ysth : Ack. You're right. The `or 1` threw me off. So is the `or 1` just contributing to line noise?

Comment: @Zaid: no, the or 1 makes sure the if is true so the print even happens - not necessary using the comma operator instead

Comment: @Zaid: if there is nothing replaces the `s///g` returns `0`, which equals `false` and so nothing is printed.  The `or 1` or `|| 1` ensures that there will always be something printed (the original string with no replacement).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make your own (for semantic reasons or otherwise), see below for an example, though `s///` should be all you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    

use strict;     

   main();   

   sub main{    
      my $foo = "blahblahblah";          
      print '$foo: ' , replace("lah","ar",$foo) , "\n";  #$foo: barbarbar

   }        

   sub replace {
      my ($from,$to,$string) = @_;
      $string =~s/$from/$to/ig;                          #case-insensitive/global (all occurrences)

      return $string;
   }
```