# Perl String - Substitute Characters without forming a new variable

Tags: perl

Is it possible to replace parts of a string without having to create a whole new variable?

Right now I do it like this:

```
$someString = "how do you do this";
$someString = s/how do/this is how/;
```

What I am trying to do is keep the original string ($someString) and be able to substitute a few characters without modifying the original string. Im more familiar with Javascript and I can do it like this in your code without having to create/modify a variable.

```
someString.replace(/how do/, "this is how")
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl: Use s/ (replace) and return new string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440363/perl-use-s-replace-and-return-new-string)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note quite sure I understand the question.  If you want to leave the original string unchanged, you need to create a new variable.

```
$newstring = $someString ;
$newstring =~ s/how do/this is how/;
```

Note that the operator is `=~` not `=`

*addition* I think I now see what you want - to return the changed string rather than modify a variable. There will be a way to do this in Perl 5.14 but I am not aware of a way at present. See [Use the /r substitution flag to work on a copy](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/) at [The Effective Perler](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/).

**Update**
The `s/ / /r` functionallity has been in released Perl for some time. you can do

```
use 5.14.0 ;
my $someString = "how do you do this";
say ($someString =~ s/how do/this is how/r) ;
```

Comment: I think he might want something like `print $someString =~ s/how do/this is how/;` but without touching `$someString`.

Comment: Good job on mentioning the new /r flag, I think thats going to be an even better addition to Perl5 than the smart match ~~

Comment: Yea, I was just looking to return the changed string rather than modify a variable. Good to see this is going to be capable soon.

Comment: You can write that in one line with `(my $newstring = $someString) =~ s/how do/this is how/;`

Answer (score 1):

You may also use lambda, i.e.:

```
sub { local $_ = shift; s/how do/this is how/; $_ }->($someString)
```

This also preserves `$_` in case you call the lambda as sub `{ }->($_)`