# Defining one string variable from another by substitution?

Tags: perl

I sometimes need two string variables, where the value of the second one is derived from the first one by character substitution.

Is there a more concise way to do it than shown below? Taking two separate commands for defining the second var from the first is bug-prone and cumbersome:

```
# Example: "pstopdf" and "ps2pdf":
my $name1 = "pstopdf";
my $name2 = $name1;
$name2 =~ s/to/2/;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl: Use s/ (replace) and return new string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440363/perl-use-s-replace-and-return-new-string)

Comment: @daxim: That's quite a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(my $name2 = $name1) =~ s/to/2/;
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the [new features in Perl 5.14](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/531) is [non-destructive substitution with the /r flag: s///r](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/659) which comes in handy if you are doing this kind of transformation in a `map`, for example.

Using the `/r` flag, you'd write

```
my $name2 = $name1 =~ s/to/2/r;
```