# Perl RegEx syntax error

Tags: regex, perl

the following code snippet taken from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace  gives me

> Bareword found where operator expected at blub.pl line 2, near
>   "s/dogs/cats/r"

What's the problem here? I'm using Perl 5.12.4 on Windows XP.

Code:

```
$x = "I like dogs.";
$y = $x =~ s/dogs/cats/r;
print "$x $y\n";
```

Comment: Um, exactly what it says? What's the `r` on the end?

Comment: @BrianRoach It's the non-destructive modifier

Comment: Erm, ok. SO, I was right ... but only because I've never used perl 5.14 :-D

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440363/perl-use-s-replace-and-return-new-string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation for Perl 5.14. That example does not appear in [the documentation for Perl 5.12](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.4/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace).

You can see that it is marked as a new feature in the [perl 5.13.2 delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5132delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution).

You can copy the variable and *then* modify it to achieve the same effect in older versions of Perl.

```
$x = "I like dogs.";
$y = $x;
$y =~ s/dogs/cats/;
print "$x $y\n";
```

Or you could use the idiomatic "one-liner":

```
$x = "I like dogs.";
($y = $x) =~ s/dogs/cats/;
print "$x $y\n";
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of why folks should not read Perl's docs on the interweb. You should instead read Perl's docs on the system where you will be running perl. Then you never suffer the round-and-round of version mismatches!

Comment: @tadmc : You can at least (carefully) select the Perl version for the documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the same version (on Linux) and getting the same error plus

> Unquoted string "r" may conflict with future reserved word

and it works when I remove r.  That tutorial is from 5.14, it may be that the `r` feature wasn't yet implemented in 5.12.