# assign to a variable the result of another variable modified with regexp

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I perform a Perl substitution on a string while keeping the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836/how-do-i-perform-a-perl-substitution-on-a-string-while-keeping-the-original)
>   [Perl: Use s/ (replace) and return new string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440363/perl-use-s-replace-and-return-new-string)

please, fell free to modify the title of this question if you find a better way to describe it.

Imagine we have:

```
   my $foo = something;
   my $newfoo = $foo =~ s/.*/something else/;
```

I thought I will have `$newfoo = something else`, while I found it equal to 1. I imagine that this 1 is there to say 'matching and replacing succeed'.

The only solution I've found is the sequent:

```
  my $foo = something;
  my $newfoo = $foo;
  $newfoo =~ s/.*/something else/;
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same task, i.e. creating a new variable with the result of the regexp without modifying the first variable, without the middle step?

Comment: Your two code snippets have different semantics.  In the first, `$foo` is modified, but not in the second.  Which behavior do you want?

Comment: Are you asking, for some variable A, how to create a new variable B that is the result of a regex find-replace on variable A?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I want to save $foo and to set $newfoo as the result of the regexp.

Comment: @AndrewKozak, Exactly! What I want to know is if it is possibile to do it without first declaring B = A.

Comment: Actually, it fits perfect here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836/how-do-i-perform-a-perl-substitution-on-a-string-while-keeping-the-original. It's the same question. I didn't find it. Is it possible to close this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign and perform the substitution in any version of Perl with judicious use of parentheses:

```
(my $newfoo = $foo) =~ s/.*/something else/;
```

Using Perl v5.14 saves you one keystroke in this case (although there may be other benefits to v5.14)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [perl 5.14](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod) or better, this will work.  It's called [non-destructive substitution](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Non-destructive_substitution).  Otherwise you'll have to stick with the temporary assignment:

```
my $newfoo = $foo =~ s/.*/something else/r;
                                         ^ Add this
```

Comment: If you're using perl 5.14 or better, consider yourself lucky.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about this new feature. However... I'm not lucky, according to J-16 SDiZ. :D Great comment.